# how to add delay in Nginx response

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lua, webserver, nginx-config

To mock the API I have to create an endpoint on Nginx and the response time should match as I receive from the actual API.

I tried to find help online and came to know that, this echo module can help: https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module
But this module does not support nginx 1.17.0 or above and my nginx version is above the supported version.

I also came to know that lua script can also be used but I found that lua script and nginx integrations is not for beginner.

Comment: Explain why you need a delay? Dobyou want to mimic and actual api response? If so, this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @Gerhard no I don't want to mimic the response, I just want to mimic the delay over API(network io), as I am using threads in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient solution that I found for this use case is [nginx-extras](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/) which comes with already added extra nginx modules and it have echo module as well, which I was looking.
You can find more available modules of your need by clicking the link.